# Qemu support for ACPI 2.0+

Tags: qemu, acpi

I'm learning x86-64 kernel, and moving from Windows to Linux.

My Qemu version is 4.2 and running in the following command:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -machine q35 -cpu Broadwell -accel kvm Boot.disk
```

It seems the ACPI version of Qemu is 0 and is using RSDT instead of XSDT.

So how can I enable ACPI 2.0+ on 64 bit Qemu?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Doesn't ACPI is part of firmware part of the virtual machine? Like BIOS or anything else you are using.

Comment: @0andriy, So what you mean is Qemu does not support ACPI 2.0+?? Sorry for the lat reply, I was at work......

Comment: No, I mean that QEmu has nothing to do with it, or does it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to firstly check if ACPI 2.0 is available in the ROM. I recall that QEMU uses SeaBIOS which might be too old.

Another option is to check "-acpitable" command line option. It can let QEMU to load additional ACPI table. So if BIOS does not have what you want, you could add it to the additional table.